# FutureBuilder stuck at circular progress bar?

Tags: json, flutter, rest, listview

I have a vendors page where tap on a listview item and it takes me to another page called categories where I try to show the categories from an API call which requires an ID from the vendors page which I pass to the constructor of Categories... The issue is in the categories page where I get actual data from the API but doesn't show up and it's stuck at circular progress bar...

> CategoriesList.dart

```
class CategoriesList extends StatefulWidget {
  final int vendorId;
  const CategoriesList({super.key, required this.vendorId});

  @override
  State<CategoriesList> createState() => _CategoriesListState();
}

class _CategoriesListState extends State<CategoriesList> {
  final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
  String token = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    retrieveToken();
  }

  Future<void> retrieveToken() async {
    String? token = await _storage.read(key: 'jwt_token');
    setState(() {
      this.token = token!;
    });
    log(token!, name: 'token from categories page');
  }

  Future<List<CategoryModel>> fetchCategory(String token) async {
    var url =
        'http://example.com/api/Category/isActive?vendor_id=${widget.vendorId}';

    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List mapData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<CategoryModel> categories =
          mapData.map((category) => CategoryModel.fromJson(category)).toList();
      return categories;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load category: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Categories:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Flexible(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<CategoryModel>>(
                  future: fetchCategory(token),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<CategoryModel>? categories = snapshot.data;
                      return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: categories?.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
                              ),
                              height: 75,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 4, right: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8),
                              child: ListTile(
                                onTap: () => {
                                  // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  //     builder: (context) => Storefront()))
                                  //log(token.toString(), name: 'token when click'),
                                },
                                leading: Image.network(
                                  "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2637581.jpg",
                                  width: 70,
                                  height: 70,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                ),
                                title: Text(categories![index].name),
                                subtitle: Text('categories[index].description'),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    } else {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> CategoriesModel.dart is my model class generated from https://quicktype.io/

```
import 'dart:convert';

class CategoryModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String createdAt;
  final String updatedAt;
  final bool isActive;
  final CategoryModel brandClass;
  final UserClass userClass;
  final dynamic vendorClass;

  CategoryModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.brandClass,
    required this.userClass,
    required this.vendorClass,
  });

  factory CategoryModel.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      CategoryModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory CategoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CategoryModel(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        description: json["description"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
        isActive: json["isActive"],
        brandClass: CategoryModel.fromJson(json["brandClass"]),
        userClass: UserClass.fromJson(json["userClass"]),
        vendorClass: json["vendorClass"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
        "isActive": isActive,
        "brandClass": brandClass.toJson(),
        "userClass": userClass.toJson(),
        "vendorClass": vendorClass,
      };
}

class UserClass {
  final int id;
  final dynamic email;
  final dynamic password;
  final String name;
  final dynamic mobile;
  final dynamic description;
  final bool isActive;
  final dynamic createdAt;
  final dynamic updatedAt;
  final dynamic userRoleClass;
  final dynamic userVerificationClass;

  UserClass({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.name,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.description,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.userRoleClass,
    required this.userVerificationClass,
  });

  factory UserClass.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      UserClass.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory UserClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserClass(
        id: json["id"],
        email: json["email"],
        password: json["password"],
        name: json["name"],
        mobile: json["mobile"],
        description: json["description"],
        isActive: json["isActive"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
        userRoleClass: json["userRoleClass"],
        userVerificationClass: json["userVerificationClass"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "name": name,
        "mobile": mobile,
        "description": description,
        "isActive": isActive,
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
        "userRoleClass": userRoleClass,
        "userVerificationClass": userVerificationClass,
      };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting debug points? is `snapshot.data` getting the data or not.

Comment: `future: fetchCategory(token),` is BROKEN.  Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thank you Randal, I'm the same guy from Discord, I watched the video and solved the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want it to stop spinning if no data is found... if should try this check

```
Flexible(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<CategoryModel>>(
                  future: fetchCategory(token),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text("Return some text"),
                      );
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<CategoryModel>? categories = snapshot.data;
                      return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: categories?.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
                              ),
                              height: 75,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 4, right: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8),
                              child: ListTile(
                                onTap: () => {
                                  // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  //     builder: (context) => Storefront()))
                                  //log(token.toString(), name: 'token when click'),
                                },
                                leading: Image.network(
                                  "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2637581.jpg",
                                  width: 70,
                                  height: 70,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                ),
                                title: Text(categories![index].name),
                                subtitle: Text(categories[index].description),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    } else {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
```

Comment: The issue was fetchCategory being called more than once...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with FutureBuilder getting called more than once, apparently you have to make sure that FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder is only called once...

```
var _categories; // later I pass this to the FutureBuilder 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _categories = fetchCategory(token);
  }
```

In the FutureBuilder,

```
future: _categories,
```